# Spark timeout exception while writing on HDFS - java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds]

Tags: scala, apache-spark, hadoop, apache-spark-sql, azure-hdinsight

Appreciate your help in advance. It's 2nd day I kept trying all permutations and combinations, could not find any solution.

1. I have setup hadoop/spark with 4 nodes on azurehdinsight
2. I have simple scala code which reads from HDFS and does simple operations like
   make column to lowercase, etc. Small file 434KB with 2300 records
   with 14 columns.
3. The code works on my local laptop(win 10) & also on
   Azure Ubuntu VM standalone cluster.
4. Problem - While writing into
   CSV, it throws java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed
   out after [100000 milliseconds] Noticed that I have few partial
   files on output location, i.e. `/data/8/1/data.csv` with
   `/data/8/1/data.csv/_temporary`
5. Important code segments:

`def get_spark(): SparkSession = {
      val spark = org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession.builder
      .appName("My App").enableHiveSupport().getOrCreate;
      return spark
    }`

```
val spark = get_spark()
val o_file = "/data/8/1/data.csv"
val loader = new Loader(spark)
var df = loader.load(i_file)
logger.info("Writing output to: {}", o_file)
df.write.mode("overwrite").option("header", "true").csv(o_file)<--throwing error here
```

And the exception is:

`18/11/29 19:06:05 INFO LoaderProcessor: Writing output to: /data/8/1/data.csv 18/11/29 19:07:37 ERROR ApplicationMaster: Uncaught exception: java.util.concurrent.TimeoutException: Futures timed out after [100000 milliseconds] at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:219) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.result(Promise.scala:223) at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitResult(ThreadUtils.scala:201) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:498) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:345) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:260) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anon$5.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:815) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:814) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:259) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:839) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala) 18/11/29 19:07:37 ERROR FileFormatWriter: Aborting job null. java.lang.InterruptedException at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.doAcquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:998) at java.util.concurrent.locks.AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.acquireSharedInterruptibly(AbstractQueuedSynchronizer.java:1304) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.tryAwait(Promise.scala:202) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:218) at scala.concurrent.impl.Promise$DefaultPromise.ready(Promise.scala:153) at org.apache.spark.util.ThreadUtils$.awaitReady(ThreadUtils.scala:222) at org.apache.spark.scheduler.DAGScheduler.runJob(DAGScheduler.scala:633) at org.apache.spark.SparkContext.runJob(SparkContext.scala:2034) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.FileFormatWriter$.write(FileFormatWriter.scala:194) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.run(InsertIntoHadoopFsRelationCommand.scala:154) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:104) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:102) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.DataWritingCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:122) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155) at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter$anonfun$runCommand$1.apply(DataFrameWriter.scala:654) at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SQLExecution$.withNewExecutionId(SQLExecution.scala:77) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.runCommand(DataFrameWriter.scala:654) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.saveToV1Source(DataFrameWriter.scala:273) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:267) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.save(DataFrameWriter.scala:225) at org.apache.spark.sql.DataFrameWriter.csv(DataFrameWriter.scala:642) at zettasense.LoaderProcessor.execute(LoaderProcessor.scala:81) at zettasense.Processor$.main(Processor.scala:47) at zettasense.Processor.main(Processor.scala) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anon$4.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:721`

**MORE INFO**

Also noticed that the "write" operation keeps on writing on output folder like this:

```
part-00000-3e9566ae-c13c-468a-8732-e7b8a8df5335-c000.csv
part-00000-3e9566ae-c13c-468a-8732-e7b8a8df5335-c001.csv
---
```

and then in few seconds:

```
part-00000-4f4979a0-d9f9-481b-aac4-115e63b9f59c-c000.csv
part-00000-4f4979a0-d9f9-481b-aac4-115e63b9f59c-c001.csv
---
```

To validate it, I did repartioning like this:

`df = df.repartition(1)`

Noticed the same thing. it keeps writing file again and again.

---

I also get this exception now:

`java.lang.IllegalStateException: User did not initialize spark context! at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.runDriver(ApplicationMaster.scala:510) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.org$apache$spark$deploy$yarn$ApplicationMaster$runImpl(ApplicationMaster.scala:345) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anonfun$run$2.apply$mcV$sp(ApplicationMaster.scala:260) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anonfun$run$2.apply(ApplicationMaster.scala:260) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$anon$5.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:815) at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) at org.apache.hadoop.security.UserGroupInformation.doAs(UserGroupInformation.java:1869) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.doAsUser(ApplicationMaster.scala:814) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.run(ApplicationMaster.scala:259) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster$.main(ApplicationMaster.scala:839) at org.apache.spark.deploy.yarn.ApplicationMaster.main(ApplicationMaster.scala)`

Comment: Did you try writing to **HDFS** instead of local directory?

Comment: I am writing on **HDFS**,  /data/8/1/data.csv is a **HDFS** path!